# Using Google OAuthUtil in a desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, google-contacts-api

I am building a Desktop application that interacts with Google Contacts. I have been trying to authenticate the application using google supplied OAuthUtil, but cant get it to work...

it seems it is only suitable for webapplication because of the callback url you have to provide, I think that because the function OAuthUtil.GetUnauthorizedRequestToken returns void...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with C# or I'd try and write some example code.  However, looking at their docs you have to open a web browser and detect whatever callback you sent.  When you detect the callback you then redirect to the client program.
http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuthForInstalledApps.html

It seems they're working on being able to make a REST request to their servers so that you don't have to have a web browser. http://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/UXFedLogin/nobrowser/input-capable-devices

Even for things, without a web browser they're current suggestion is to provide a pin, which you then have the user register on a device with a web browser.
http://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/UXFedLogin/nobrowser